# How to upload dynamically generated input files using spring boot?

Tags: java, html, spring

I have a building class which contains list of floors. I want to upload floor map for each building and i need to generated input type file elements dynamically for each floor.

```
public class Floor{
   private String floorId,
   private String floorLevel;
   @Lob
   private byte[] map;
}

public class Building {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private List<Floor> floors;

}
```

I need to generate input fields dynamically something similar to [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Dynamically-Add-More-Form-Fields-czMore). How should i handle the controller method for receiving the form data.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you facing any issues? Do you know how to handle file upload in spring-boot?

Comment: @Tushar i can upload file using MultipartFile.But in this usecase how should i write controller method